# Angular is not defined in Gulp uglified file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

```js
//ERRRORS SHOWN ON THE CONSOLE

main.lib.angular.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noop' of undefined
main.lib.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
main.user.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
(index):52 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

I'm writing a Gulp file for my app. The app uses AngularJS and it's libraries and few other libraries. But when I uglify the JS files and concatenate all the library files into one and all the user defined JS files into one, I get an error saying angular is not defined. I've kept the sequence of the uglified-concatenated file such that the file with angular libraries comes first during compilation. But, since there are more angular files, other than the angular.js which come before the angular.js, I get an error. Is there a solution to this issue? Also, if I don't concatenate the angular library files and import them as such, I still get error for the other injected modules as not defined. Here is the gulpfile.js I've written:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync')
reload = browserSync.reload,
  concat = require('gulp-concat')
cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

var dest = './dest/'

//Angular apps
gulp.task('script-lib-ang', function() {
  gulp.src('./lib/angular/*.js')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(uglify({
      mangle: false
    }))
    .pipe(concat('main.lib.angular.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

//Task for all the library javascript files
gulp.task('script-lib', ['script-lib-ang'], function() {
  gulp.src(['./lib/**/*.js', '!./lib/angular/*.js'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(uglify({
      mangle: false
    }))
    .pipe(concat('main.lib.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

//Task for all custom js files developed by the user
gulp.task('script-user', ['script-lib'], function() {
  gulp.src('./app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(uglify({
      mangle: false
    }))
    .pipe(concat('main.user.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

// gulp.task('css-user', function() {
//  gulp.src(['./css/**/*.css', '!./css/lib/*.css'])
//   .pipe(plumber())
//   .pipe(cleanCSS())
//   .pipe(concat('css-user.css'))
//   .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
//   .pipe(reload({stream : true}));
// });

gulp.task('css-lib', function() {
  gulp.src('./css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(concat('css-lib.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync({
    proxy: 'localhost',
    ui: false
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./lib/angular/*.js', ['script-lib-ang']);
  gulp.watch(['./lib/**/*.js', '!./lib/angular/*.js'], ['script-lib']);
  gulp.watch('./app/**/*.js', ['script-user']);
  gulp.watch('./css/**/*.css', ['css-lib']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['script-lib-ang', 'script-lib', 'script-user', 'css-lib', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Could you mention the exact error string.

Comment: @Aman Gupta I've added the console error in the post

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bower for client side dependencies and use a npm package like main-bower-files it will sort all your library files in the right order. And to achieve the correct order for your project flies I would name them explicitly like *.controler.js, *.module.js. THis way you can use the extension to figure out the order.

As an example I will declare a variable with the right order of files and a require for main-bower-files package like:

```
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var jsFilesLocation: [
             appRoot + '**/*.module.js',
            appRoot + '**/*.config.js',
            appRoot + '**/*.service.js',
            appRoot + '**/*.controller.js',
            appRoot + '**/*.js'
        ];

/*Now using the Jsfileslocation and the main-bower-files plugin my task will look like*/

gulp.task('inject-js', function () {

        return gulp.src(config.indexHtmlFileLocation)
         /* Inject bower references */
         .pipe(plugins.inject(gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), { read: false }),
         /*Inject Code Files */
         .pipe(plugins.inject(gulp.src(jsFilesLocation, { read: false }),
            { relative: true }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(destinationPath));
    });
```

If yo follow this pattern you should not get any erros. Here is link for a great article on how to improve the gulp taks:

http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-and-gulp/

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: In this app we're using libraries saved offline on our system. So not using bower. Is there a way that without using bower we still can define the sequence of concatenation of files?

Comment: In that case you have to add manually the files you need in the right order to a variable just like jsFileLocations. This would be the quick and dirty way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [gulp-ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate) to manage all concatenated angularjs files before minifying it. This is an example of the task for concat and minifying all js files :

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.development.js)
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(ngannotate())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(selectedConfig.ENV.name + '/dist/js'))
});
```

Comment: I tried using your solution, but even that didn't work.;-(